# В чем различие между двумя формами директивы #include: в кавычках и в скобках?

Tags: c, include, c++

```
#include "some.h"
```

и

```
#include <some.h>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Различие в том, где препроцессор будет начинать поиск файла *some.h*. Если использовать директиву `#include "some.h"`, то сначала будут просмотрены **локальные** (по отношению к проекту) папки включения файлов. Если использовать `#include <some.h>`, то сначала будут просматриваться **глобальные** (по отношению к проекту) папки включения файлов. Глобальные папки включения - это папки, прописанные в настройке среды разработки, локальные - это те, которые прописаны в настройках проекта.

Comment: Не понятно, а что будет потом?
В случае если используется директива #include "some.h" и файл не найден в локальных папках, то поиск будет осуществляться в глобальных.

В случае если используется директива #include <some.h> поиск в локальных папках производиться не будет, а сразу приступи к поиску в глобальных папках.

Answer (score 10):

Согласно главе `16.2 Source file inclusion [cpp.include]`, отличие `"path"` и `<path>` в том, что `"path"` делает всё то же самое, что и `<path>`, но сначала она будет искать в некотором дополнительном наборе файлов.

В существующих компиляторах это реализовано следующим образом:

`#include <path>` ищет в путях переданных компилятору с помощью параметра командной строки (`-I`), в путях заданных переменными окружения, в путях вшитых в компилятор.

`#include "path"` ищет в директории в которой находится текущий файл, и затем ищет там же где и `#include <path>`.

В [VC++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4.aspx) `#include "path"` также ищет в директориях других файлов, включенных в эту единицу трансляции.

В [G++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html#Include-Syntax) `#include "path"` также ищет в директориях, указанных в параметре командной строки `-iquote`.

Answer (score 0):

> Не понятно, а что будет потом? В случае если используется директива #include "some.h" и файл не найден в локальных папках, то поиск будет осуществляться в глобальных. В случае если используется директива #include  поиск в локальных папках производиться не будет, а сразу приступи к поиску в глобальных папках.

Вы можете в заголовочных файлах создать свою библиотеку, допустим популярную `"iostream.h"`
Так вот если вы в проекте будете писать "iostream.h" то он будет использовать ваш заголовочный файл. А если `<iostream.h>` глобальный.