# Не находит файлы библиотеки SFML

Tags: c++, библиотеки, include, sfml

Работаю на ubuntu 14.04LTS. В папке где лежит сам *GUI_test.cpp* есть папка *SFML*, в ней все hpp'ешки. Так вот: указываю `#include </SFML/Graphics.hpp>`, а в ответ компилятор пишет:

> `g++ -Wall -o "GUI_test" "GUI_test.cpp" (в каталоге: /home/tms5978/test_c++/gui)
>   GUI_test.cpp:1:30: fatal error: /SFML/Graphics.hpp: Нет такого файла или каталога
>    #include </SFML/Graphics.hpp>
>                      ^
>   compilation terminated.
>   Сборка завершилась с ошибкой.`

Хотя все файлы лежат там.

Comment: А почему вы начинаете путь со `/`? У вас реально каталог SFML лежит в корне?

Comment: Вы не поверите, но в никсах если путь начинается с "/" - это абсолютный путь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже указано в комментариях к вопросу: `/` задает коренной каталог файловой системы. Если нужно сослаться на текущий каталог, то достаточно убрать `/` или можно добавить перед ним `.`.

Другой момент в том, что для подключения заголовочных файлов не расположенных в заранее предопределенных путях следует использовать запись с двойными кавычками, а не треугольными скобками. Т.е. правильнее писать так:

```
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
```

Или внести путь, по которому расположена папка *SFML*, в список предопределенных путей (для этого можно использовать ключ `-I` компилятора) и использовать запись с треугольными скобками:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
```

О различиях между `""` и `<>` можно почитать в другой [теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/149/176217).