# C/C++, не найден <gtk/gtk.h>

Tags: c++, c, gtk

Меня замучила следующая проблема.

Для построения интерфейса я использую библиотеку **GTK+**, в роли **IDE** выступает **Code::Blocks**. Сама библиотека и все зависимости установлены-переустановлены тысячу раз.

Беда в том, что во время работы с проектом, который успешно компилировался и отлаживался, в абсолютно случайный момент времени возникает описанная ошибка, которую никак не устранить, пока она сама не пройдет.

Смена компилятора, пересоздание проекта, перезагрузка системы, изменение настроек проекта/компилятора - ничего не помогает.

Ошибка пропадает в случайный момент времени и столь же внезапно, как и появилась.

Самое забавное в этой ситуации то, что

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
```

не может найти файл лишь в некоторых файлах проекта, тогда как, например, в **main.c** никаких предупреждений на описанной строчке кода не возникает.

Что это за магия? Что с этим делать?

Comment: Пробовать компилировать проект с консоли. Если и в этом случае проблема возникает - значит скорее всего либо диск шалит, либо антивирус.

Comment: Антивируса нет, с консоли результат такой же.

Comment: Тогда надо смотреть, как именно собирается проект. Может там система сборки особая, и она не проставляет правильно пути поиска для файлов.

Comment: Я же говорю, проект собирался без проблем полчаса назад, и вдруг сломался. Ничего не менялось, ни в проекте, ни в системе, нигде. И такое уже происходит не первый раз. Не помогает даже полная переустановка стека GTK+ и Code::Blocks

Comment: @Максим, а в сборке используется паралелльная компиляция? Если да, то попробуйте выключить.

Comment: Это тоже не помогает.

Comment: Тогда тут Вам вряд ли помогут. Берите утилиты от Sysinternals и разбирайтесь с окружением. [ProcMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/processmonitor) будет хорошим стартом.

Comment: Пятая по счету перезагрузка решила проблему. Я не понимаю, как это работает.

Comment: Может винда глючит. Переустановите все с нуля и не ставьте ничего постороннего. Или попробуйте сменить машину, может действительно аппаратный сбой.

Comment: На другой железке такие приколы тоже происходят, уже убедились в этом.

Comment: Если на другой машине то же самое то значит это не винда и не аппаратура. А проект большой? Компилируете на VS2017?

Comment: У меня было похожее, когда в проекте были два хедера с одинаковым именем. То есть у меня был хедер условно с именем head.h и еще в проекте были файлы от другого программиста, и у него был другой хедер тоже с именем head.h. Вылечилось когда я переименовал свой хедер в head1.h. Причем тоже иногда компиляция проходила, а иногда нет. Но транслятор был не VS а Борланд билдер 6.0.

Comment: Что-то у вас в вопросе никакой релевантной информации нет. Вот где у вас установлена эта GTK и где конкретно лежит этот заголовочный файл? Какая система сборки используется для проекта и какой компилятор? Какие настройки сборки, и каким образом компилятор узнает о расположении этого заголовочного файла? Приведите полный текст команды компилятору при сборке, а также лог сборки.

Comment: Возможно вам стоит почитать чем `#include <file>` отличается от `#include "file"` https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/149/%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b-include-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%85

Comment: В консоли внимательно во время поломки изучите вывод на предмет не теряет ли он ключь  `-I` или пути в нем к гтк директории заголовков. Возможно по каким то причинам вся команда превышает доступный размер буфера, зависит от особенностей ос в каждом конкретном случае.

Comment: И ещё нюанс, попробуй те добавить все ключи и библиотеки GTK руками в проект, и не использовать `pkg-config` - возможно глюки идут от него. И проверьте что выдает `pkg-config gtk++3.0 --cflags`