# Как подключить заголовочный файл в другой папке?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

Вот такой вопрос, есть папка проекта в ней папка с исходным кодом и папка с заголовочными файлами, как мне подключить заголовочные файлы из их собственной папки? Дело в том, что когда я пытаюсь подключить заголовочные файлы, компилятор их не видит.

Выглядит это так:

\SDL2_Lessons\src  - папка с исходниками

\SDL2_Lessons\src_h - папка с заголовочными

[image: список папок и файлов в папке проекта] [image: ошибка подключения]

Comment: А указать что-то типа `#include "src_h/options.h"` (обратите внимание на кавычки, кстати) религия не позволяет? :)

Comment: Это не сработало( Всё та же история

Comment: Ну значит `#include "\SDL2_Lessons\src_h\options.h"` - смотрите сами, что у вас в свойствах проекта указано, где искать заголовочные файлы...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если работаете в Visual Studio то нужно открыть свойства проекта, найти `Configuration Properties->C/C++->General`. Далее найти пункт `Additional Include Directories` В нем прописать путь до вашей папки где лежат ваши заголовочные файлы. Тогда вы сможете включать заголовочные файлы через угловые скобки `#include <myheader.h>`

Либо можете не включать папку в `Additional Include Directories`, а указывать ваш файл относительно исходного файла, например `#include "../Myheaders/myheader.h"` Но тогда уже в обычных ковычках.

Comment: Разве нельзя в этом случае включать, используя и кавычки, и угловые скобки (а не или)?

Comment: @dIm0n можно, но если использовать кавычки то сначала компилятор будет искать локально, и если не найдет то пойдет искать во включенных директориях, если использовать угловые то поиск будет осуществляться в глобальных по отношению к проекту папках. Подробнее https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/150/210482

Comment: Скорее https://stackoverflow.com/q/21593/13970074. Но из ответа складывается впечатление, что можно одним способом, но нельзя другим